# Node-Red and MongoDB dynamically querying collections with msg.collection

Tags: node-red

I'm using Node-Red and the mongodb node to well, pull data from mongo.  I dynamically create databases based on events, and don't know the names of every db at any given time.  I read you can use a msg.collection method, but I don't see how to go about doing it.  Just setting the collection name in msg.collection doesn't do the trick.  Possible to pass the db name and collection name using this node, or even just the collection name?

I'm guessing there's a format to the msg.collection method i'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turned out to be a flow problem.  If you intend on setting this after a post or anything with a msg.payload, set that to "" before the mongodb node along with setting msg.collection.  The node thought I was passing a query.